# How To Make WAMP accessible by other devices Through LAN

Tags: apache, wamp

My goal is to access a WAMP Site from my phone via Wi-Fi. I am using WAMP 3

According to an answer here in Stack Overflow, I should just worry about the httpd-vhost.conf file in apache and add my IP Address like this:

````
```<Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
    Require ip 192.x.x #I have added this line
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>```
````

And so I did, the next step I did is to allow my port, which is port 8080 by the way, through Windows Firewall. And so I did.

Now, how can I access it from my phone? I've tried using the IPV4 address of my phone, like this: http://192.x.x.x:8080/ but can't access my WAMP Homepage. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: What `Require` does is in fact to restrict access. That isn't a bad idea, but perhaps you should try to set it up when you have basic access working. Now, what does "can't access" mean? The IP doesn't exist? You get an error message? Is Apache actually listening in that IP address? Is the phone connected to your local wifi?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I used ipconfig to know my IP Address, so I think it does exist. I don't get an error message. However, what I meant by can't access is that I don't know how to access the website through my phone. I tried my phone's IPV4 Address and it just said "This site can't be reached". Lastly, yes, the phone is connected to the same wifi my PC is connected

Comment: "I tried my phone's IPV4 Address" — That cannot work. Apache is not running on your phone, it's running on the Windows machine. You should possibly get a message like "This site can’t be reached".

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes I did get that. Then is it not possible to access the site from my phone? Or should I use my PC's IPV4 instead?

Comment: I'll use a simile: if you want to call a friend, you dial **his** phone number, not yours.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález so should I type http://{pc's IPV4 address}:8080 into my phone? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you should. But... Do you understand that IP addresses are to computers what phone numbers are to telephony? Why would connecting to your phone's address get stuff from any other random device?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It finally worked! Thank you very much for your help kind sir. I'm sorry for not understanding IP Addresses before doing this. I'll keep that in mind